# Amazon ec2 instance w/ atached volume permission denied with sftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sftp, amazon-ec2

I made an extra volume and then attached it like this...

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 device_name
sudo mkdir mount_point
sudo mount device_name mount_point
```

The mount point was in my home directory as well. when I try to run

```
put -r ./directory
```

It doesn't give any errors but the also doesn't transfer any of the files that are in the directory.

If I use filezilla I get some errors like this...

```
/home/ubuntu/xvdb/file.txt: open for write: permission denied
```

but when I look at the permissions of the mounted folder/drive it is owned by the user I am logged in as (stock `ubuntu` on EC2 ubuntu instance)

Why would it be giving me permissions errors?

Comment: what permissions do you have on the mountpoin/folders. Not owner

Comment: it was 755, but even tried making it 777 and it still wouldn't work